# Background color of a UITableView does not extend across the cell for iPad

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder

I've set the background color of a UITableView and its cells to a dark blue in Interface Builder, which seems to work fine for all iPhone sizes:

[image: iPhone]

However, on iPad (portrait and landscape), the color does not apply to the disclosure indicator (arrow) on the right of each cell:

[image: iPad]

I'd love to provide more details than that, but I'm not sure what else there is to say.

If I remove the cell accessory entirely, it fills the cell normally, but all of the other accessory options (checkbox, detail, etc.) have the same effect.

Any idea why?

Comment: can you provide iOS version of iPad? Did you notice the settings in IB for what iOS version you're previewing?

Comment: Sure: these screenshots are from the Simulator running iOS 8.1, but I can replicate this behavior on a real device running the same version; IB is set to iOS 7.0 and later.

Comment: are you setting the background color of each cell's contentView? Can you provide code snippet?

Comment: @RobP I'm setting the color in IB of the cell's view. Oddly enough, if I do it programmatically, it works as it should, so I might end up just doing that, but I'm curious as to why it looks fine on iPhone if that's the problem.

Comment: set cell tintcolor to white and set cell.editingAccessoryView.backgroundColor to clear color.

Comment: @the1pawan Unfortunately, that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that you cannot set the actual cell's background color from within Interface Builder (or, if you can, I couldn't find it).

So, the easiest way to do it is to set it programmatically from within your UITableView implementation methods:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 5.0/255, green: 51.0/255, blue: 103.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

What tripped me up for a while with the RGB values is that you have to divide them by 255 (if you don't, it will just show up as white).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Interface Builder by selecting "Table View Cell" and then changing its background color:

[image]